# Nested classes selectors

Tags: css

If I have something like this in my HTML

```
    <div id="top">
        <div class="txt">
            <span class="welcome">Welcome on my website</span>
            <span class="links"><a href="Home">Home</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How I can select the welcome class in my CSS.

I've tried #top.txt.welcome but doesn't work.
I've also tried #top.txt span.welcome.

Answer (score 15):

`#top .txt` is not `#top.txt`
the latter means that the matched element has the id AND the class, while the former means that the matched element has the class, and one of its ancestors element has the id

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
span.welcome
#top .welcome
#top div.txt span.welcome
.welcome
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.welcome

#top div.txt .welcome

div#top div.txt span.welcome
```

it depends on how specific you want to be

Answer (score 2):

```
#top .txt .welcome{}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
div#top div.txt span.welcome
```

or

```
#top div.txt .welcome
```

or some other variation thereof...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use that 'welcome' class for perticular span tag than you can use two ways like...

```
.txt span.welcome
```

or

```
span.welcome
```

It'll works for your CSS class in your code perfectly.

This is the concept of nesting class you can directly refer from references below.

**References:**

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/